# optimize.minimize in Python not finding the solution

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to maximize a function using optimize.minimize, but for some reason is not giving me the correct answer.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eps = 0.001
def safe_log(x):
    if x > eps:
        return math.log(x)
    logeps = np.log(eps)
    a = 1 / (3 * eps * (3 * logeps * eps)**2)
    b = eps * (1 - 3 * logeps)
    return a * (x - b)**3    

def funct(x):
    return -(( (1 - 0.45192566) * safe_log( 1 - x )) + ( 0.45192566 * safe_log( 1 + ((5.5 - 1)*x) )))

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x-1})
bnds = ((0, None),)

res = minimize(funct, (0), constraints=cons, bounds=bnds)
print("res", res.x)
print("mes", res.message)

x = []
y = []
for i in range(0, 100):
    x.append(i/100)
    y.append(funct(i/100))
    pass

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The calculated answer is 1.

If I plot the function there is a clear min as it can be seen in the picture

[image: function plot]

I have been stuck with this for a couple of days now and I cannot find answer to this.

Comment: Please post a code snippet that runs and reproduces the error when run. We can't run this.

Comment: What the heck is up with that constraint?

Comment: Your code is no good. Just copy paste it and try to run it. Can you run it? If not, then edit it. I am getting `IndexError: SLSQP Error: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0.`

Comment: Sorry, my bad guys, now it is working. First time posting here it will not happen again.

Comment: Now that this is working please consider either (a) deleting this question or (b) posting an answer to the question with details on how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You've constrained your `x` to be at least 1:

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x-1})
```

SciPy has successfully minimized your objective function subject to your bounds and constraints. Subject to those bounds and constraints, the minimum occurs at x=1.